# Discord Python - How to get the username from the user ID?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Does anyone know how to get the discord username (and discriminator) of someone given its ID?
This code does not return a username:

```
userid = '123'
username = bot.get_user_info(userid)
```

Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `bot`? I guess it's your [`discord.Client`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client) object? Then, your call to [`get_user_info`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user_info) returns an object of class [`discord.User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User). Furthermore, [`get_user_info`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user_info) is a [coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutine).

You will have to write something like this:

```
user = await bot.get_user_info(userid)
username = user.name
```

As @squaswin pointed out in the comments: Keep in mind that `await` statements have to be inside `async` functions. Otherwise a `SyntaxError` will be raised.

Comment: Are you trying to use an `await` statement in a function that isnt labeled `async def`

Comment: Good rule of thumb working with discord.py, if something says "generator", then you probably missed an await, and if that starts throwing syntax errors, you probably missed an async.