# Get Discord username from user ID (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to write a simple game in discord.py. The score is stored in a database, indexed by the Discord user ID (an integer).

Now I'd like to display the highscore in a nicely readable format.
For that, I am trying to get the Discord username (e.g. `Example#1234`) from the user ID (e.g. `354250329581841022`). I've [found](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/frameworks/django/discord.py+get+member+by+user+id) [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53579605/discord-python-how-to-get-the-username-from-the-user-id):

```
user_hs = client.get_user(user_id)
print(user_hs.name)
```

but unfortunately, `user_hs` is always None type and throws an error that it doesn't have attribute `name`.

Minimal example:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
   async def on_message(message):
      user_message = str(message.content)

      if user_message.lower() == '&hs':
         user_id = 354250329581841022
         user_hs = client.get_user(user_id)
         print(user_hs.name)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1):

What was missing was `await`. Adding that before `fetch_user` works flawlessly:

```
user = await client.fetch_user(id)
await message.channel.send(f'{user}: {score} points')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
client.get_user(id_)
```

This works, then you can get its username this way:

```
client.get_user(id_).name
```

If the returned value is `None`, probably the user just doesn't exist.